# Include a website inside android project

Tags: android, webview

I have a small offline web that at some point my application will show through a webview.

Where should I put the website in my android resources folder in order to be able to load all the javascripts, css etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check assets, i think its exactly what you want.

Here is how I use assests. My hierarchy:

- **assets**

| - help.html

| - some.js

| - **images**

| - | - banner.jpg

| - | - bg.jpg

then in app, I use WebView as layout. Then;

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere in the bundle resources. When opening from the WebView, you can provide the URL into your bundle as base URL, and scripts, styles, etc. will load as expected.

Comment: YES!!! Sorry, iPhone crosstalk. Asstes is fine, and as a base URL you give something like `"file:///android_asset/my_folder/"`. Even though assets are not a physical folder, WebView resolves this correctly.